# How could I start a crowdfunding campaign in order to Terraform Venus?

Tags: terraforming

Venus is actually a better candidate for colonization in some regards thanks to its proximity to the Earth, thick atmosphere, and Earth-like gravity, and like the Earth, it resides within the solar system's habitable zone. We also know it can hold an atmosphere, and it has nearly the same mass and size as Earth. Mars, on the other hand, is considerably smaller, and would pose serious health risks to humans (reduced muscle mass and bone density) on account of its low gravity.

In the 1990s, Paul Birch proposed a plan that would see Venus flooded with over 4x1019 kg of hydrogen. This would cause a reaction with the CO2, which would in turn produce graphite and water — a lot of water. His estimates predicted that about 80% of the surface area of Venus would eventually be covered in water (compared to Earth's 70%).

The United Arab Emirates president Sheikh Khalifa bin Zayed Al Nahyan has had the nation's top scientific minds secretly toiling for years to create a new means of weather manipulation that would work more effectively in the region's extreme temperatures. The result: The biggest Ionic Breeze on Earth.
 Ionic Breeze devices are giant ionizers mounted atop tall steel poles and were built by the Swiss company, Metro Systems International. The devices generate massive ionic fields, positively charged ions ground back to the Earth while the negatively charged ions rise into the atmosphere. As they rise, the negative ions (electrons) collect particles of dust on the way up. These flecks act as seeds for ice crystal formation, much as silver iodide does except without the need for clouds. As long as the atmospheric humidity is at least 30 percent, the system supposedly works even in clear skies.

The surface of Venus is far too hot, and the atmosphere too dense, for Human life or most machinery. But the air on Venus thins out and cools considerably as you rise above the surface; about 30 miles up you hit the sweet spot for human habitation.  The atmospheric pressure there is the same as Earth sea level (1 bar). Temperatures are perfect for Earth life too, just over 0°C.

Proposal:

House Ionic breeze devices within floating laboratories and manipulate the weather in order to shield the planet from solar radiation from the sun as well as increase hydrogen and oxygen within the atmosphere.

Comment: Interesting concept. You ask about how to start a crowdfunding campaign, but that's a bit vague! Do you already have a budget, or do you need that from us? Are you asking for a fictional marketing strategy? Is there a pending apocalypse that would drive the common people to donate, or are you targeting adventurous pioneers? I'm somewhat familiar with [Birch's Venusian terraforming](http://www.orionsarm.com/fm_store/TerraformingVenusQuickly.pdf) idea, and it takes about two *centuries.* (If I pay, who gets to go? My 8th-great-grandchild?) And what are the world's governments doing about it?

Comment: Hi welcome to the site I like to encourage you to start small do a clinical trial to build up people trust in your ideal like reversing global warming here on Earth! Unfortunately my retirement fund goes to Mars else...

Comment: Hi Red Cole, and welcome to Worldbuilding SE and Stack Exchange. As type_outcast mentioned in a previous comment, it's not entirely clear exactly what you are asking for. I'm putting the question on hold for the moment; can you [edit] your question to indicate which exact aspect you need help with? I also recommend that you familiarize yourself with [What topics can I ask about here?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), both in our site's [help].

Comment: Tell a bunch of extremely wealthy people that they will get some kind of return on their investment. Use science-y terms that confuse them and they will throw money at you.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Most wealthy people didn't get that way by throwing money at people.

Comment: @Samuel I was referring to the ones born into wealth.